# Trouble generating beep in C code in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning about device drivers and want to write a kernel module which can generate a sound from pcspkr. I have used the following code in my module:

```
static void play_sound(uint32_t nFrequence)
{
    uint32_t Div;
    uint8_t tmp;

    //Set the PIT to the desired frequency
    Div = 1193180 / nFrequence;
    outb(0x43, 0xb6);
    outb(0x42, (uint8_t)(Div));
    outb(0x42, (uint8_t)(Div >> 8));

    //And play the sound using the PC speaker
    tmp = inb(0x61);
    if (tmp != (tmp | 3))
    {
        outb(0x61, tmp | 3);
    }
}

//make it shutup
static void nosound(void)
{
    uint8_t tmp = inb(0x61) & 0xFC;
    outb(0x61, tmp);
}

//Make a beep
void beep(void)
{
    static int ev = 1;
    if(ev)
    {
        play_sound(1000);
        ev = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        nosound();
        ev = 1;
    }
    //set_PIT_2(old_frequency);
}
```

This generates no sound at all. I have tried generating sound through a normal c program using `ioctl(console_fd, KIOCSOUND, 1193180 / freq)` but even this doesn't work.

After further investigation, I installed `beep`, ran `sudo modprobe pcspkr`, checked volume levels in `alsamixer`.

`printf '\a'` works and produces a short sound.

`beep` also produces the same sound before `sudo modprobe pcspkr` but does not produce any sound after it.

I ran `speaker-test` and it works as expected and produces a beep at a desired frequency.

Am I missing something? Please help me figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a PC speaker installed? Your other methods of producing sound might be sending the sound to a system speaker instead.

Comment: @S.S.Anne `lsmod` displays pcspkr.

Comment: Yes, but that's the module. Do you have a physical PC speaker installed in your device?

Comment: How do I check if it exists? I thought running `speaker-test` was sufficient?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I cannot see an entry of "PC Speaker" in `alsamixer` nor any entry "Beep". Although it did show an entry "Beep" when I tried all of this in Ubuntu in a VM.

Comment: You probably don't have one then.

Comment: So in what other way can I make a sound from my kernel module?

Comment: Well, you could use ALSA or OSS or PulseAudio.

Comment: Does `echo ^G` emit a sound from your PC? (that is Ctrl-G, pressed at the same time). Good luck.

Comment: Yes it does. The ubuntu beep/bell sound.

Comment: If you are printing the ASCII BEL (Ctrl-G) character to a terminal emulator such as a Gnome Terminal window, it will be up to the terminal emulator what it does with the character. It might play a sound, flash the terminal, or whatever, but it probably won't play a beep or bell in the same way as the Linux virtual console devices (such as /dev/tty0). VC devices trigger an `EV_SND` input event to play the sound through a registered input handler. The "pcspkr" and "snd-pcsp" drivers both register handlers that use the old PC speaker interface. There may be other handlers e.g. "snd-hda-codec".